# SQL- how to find the top 1 row?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have to find the top 1 row of effective_date for each account

```
account    dt_effective
-------------------------
1    14-04-2012
1    15-04-2012
2    13-02-2011
2    11-03-2012
3    1-01-2010
3    02-02-2010
3    05-01-2012
```

answer have to be :

```
account     dt_effective
-------------------------
1    14-04-2012
2    13-02-2011
3    1-01-2010
```

can you please help me with the query to find this?

*updated the question*

Comment: @SherifMaherEaid: order by ll still give me the entire set of values but i want the top 1 for each account only

Comment: Your expected result doesn't make sense. For account = 3 you are taking the oldest dt_effective but for account = 1 your are taking the newest dt_effective.

Comment: The devil is in the detail on this - people are not spotting that in the results, the account 1 uses the max, whilst account 2 and 3 is using a minimum - so by top 1, you mean first entry within the table? in which case, what field have we to denoted when it was added?

Comment: @Andrew: ya u r right..i need the first entry within table for that only i am using this dt_effective column.

Comment: So for account=1 you need 14-04-2012?

Comment: So then, for the account 1 it should be 14-04 and not 15-04

Comment: Please phrase the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
SELECT account, MIN(dt_effective) FROM your_table
GROUP BY account
```

Comment: @ResKing: if for account=1 you need 14-02 my answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT account, MAX(dt_effective)
FROM [table]
GROUP BY account
```

Comment: Accidentally edited this answer instead of my own.  I've rolled back my edits now (and deleted my own since it was the same as this).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT account, MAX(dt_effective)
FROM yourTableName
GROUP BY account
```

if you need the first effective date entered just change max to min

```
SELECT account, MIN(dt_effective)
FROM yourTableName
GROUP BY account
```

Comment: Your second query is exactly the one I gave OP long time ago thinking about a typo in his question :)

Comment: Oh yes, I just saw your answer. I am still not sure what he wants, so included both of them :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select account, MAX(dt_effective) from table group by account;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below mentioned query and works as expected.

```
    DECLARE @T TABLE(ACCOUNTID INT, ACCOUNTDATE DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @T
VALUES(1,    CONVERT(DATE,'14-04-2012',105))
INSERT INTO @T
VALUES(1,    CONVERT(DATE,'15-04-2012',105))
INSERT INTO @T
VALUES(2,    CONVERT(DATE,'13-02-2011',105))
INSERT INTO @T
VALUES(2,    CONVERT(DATE,'11-03-2012',105))
INSERT INTO @T
VALUES(3,    CONVERT(DATE,'1-01-2010',105))
INSERT INTO @T
VALUES(3,   CONVERT(DATE,'02-02-2010',105))
INSERT INTO @T
VALUES(3,    CONVERT(DATE,'05-01-2012',105))

SELECT * FROM @T

SELECT ACCOUNTID, MAX(ACCOUNTDATE) FROM @T
GROUP BY ACCOUNTID
```

Comment: Did you check the answers he mentioned ?? Do you get the same answers ? All the three ??

Comment: Did you read our comments before posting the same answer given from many others? :)

Comment: Yeah, it was my fault. I was in middle of something when I started posting the answer. When I posted my answer other answers on same line were already posted. apologies for this.